# android download image and show widget's picture

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I try to set image from url with remote view. Here is the code that I use.
I debugged my code and my String

```
(this: String ab = (MainActivity.itemList.get(0)
                    .get(MainActivity.KEY_image)).toString();) is for example some image's url (for example,http://google.com/mypic.png)
```

This is my code :

```
RemoteViews views;
    int appWidgetId;
    public File file;
    public Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        if (CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "onReceiver()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intent, 0);

            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_demo);
            String aa = (MainActivity.itemList.get(0)
                    .get(MainActivity.KEY_title)).toString();

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetPic, pendingIntent);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetDesc, pendingIntent);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetDesc, aa);
            String ab = (MainActivity.itemList.get(0)
                    .get(MainActivity.KEY_image)).toString();


            views.setImageViewUri(R.id.widgetPic, Uri.parse(ab));

            // views.setImageViewBitmap(
            // R.id.widgetPic,
            // ((BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(
            // R.drawable.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)).getBitmap());

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    public void updateAppWidget(Context context,
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_demo);
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
    }

}
```

How can I show this image with `setImageViewUri` ? If anyone knows solution please help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are u sure image available into your path?

Comment: do you have a solution ?

Comment: you add `imageview` and try to set `setImageViewUri` to it. why r u set this `uri` to `remoteview` itself?

Comment: in my option solution is setimageviewUri  but not working.do you have another idea ?

Comment: Where is your images?? i mean in sdcard.

Comment: no image is not in sdcard image is in server for example like this (http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg)

Comment: then u need to download first this images and then try to set to your view.

Comment: thank you .i also wrote code to download image to server but i can not to show in widget. please see my code ... i tested my downloader code in another project with imageview and working but in widget i can not to show image  (https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpi5z14v05myux1/ApiWidget.java)

Comment: you go wrong over here in your code in onPostExecute(){  views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widgetPic, result); but here your views==null then how can u set bitmap?

Comment: i added if (views != null) then ....  but also not working in your option what is a solution ? how i can to change my code

Comment: i have another solution for this but i continue this discussion into chat but u have not enough reputation. is there any way?

Comment: hmmm if you can help me i need widget's image.pleae